# Server evaluated search for multiple keywords using linq and c#

Tags: c#, search, linq-to-sql, .net-6.0

It seems like a trivial task, yet searching stackoverflow and the internet I have failed to find a good solution.

I'm implementing simple search functionality taking a string as input and extract the keywords. Next step is to apply the keywords into a query. I have tried to code below, but linq throws an error to change from Server-evaluation to Client-Evalutaion using .AsEnumerable

But I want to do the evalutation on the server and I want to do as much in one round trip as possible. I guess the problem in my code is related to the .Any/.Contains pattern, but I hope someone can help.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}

List<string> keywords = new List<string> { "John", "Doe" };
IEnumerable<Person> persons = await context.PersonDbSet
    .Where(person => keywords.Any(keyword => person.Name.Contains(keyword)) 
        || keywords.Any(keyword => person.Email.Contains(keyword)))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: What's the actual error? And what are you trying to do? Entity Framework will translate LINQ to SQL but can't do things that are impossible in SQL. Besides, the `LIKE '%..%'` generated by `person.Email.Contains(keyword)` can't use any indexes and would result in a full table scan. If the `Persons` table has a lot of rows this will result in very slow performance. It will also cause a lot of blocking as such a query would take Shared locks on all table rows, blocking writers

Comment: What you tried to do could only be represented with an ugly `WHERE Name like '%John' or Name like '%Doe%' or Email like '%John%' or Email like '%Doe%'`. You could use SQL Server's [Full Text Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15) indexes and use them through EF's full text search functions like [EF.FreeText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.freetext?view=efcore-5.0) or `EF.Contains`

Comment: `It seems like a trivial task,` it's not, it's one of the most inefficient queries. That's why almost all autocomplete filters use `StartsWith` instead of `Contains`. Or use a dedicated full text search engine like Elastic

Comment: May I should emphasize keywords could hold n keywords, thus the query must accomodate any number of keywords.

Comment: You can't have an arbitrary number of keywords if you want to have acceptable performance. Although even if you have to write 1000 `OR`s, `CONTAINS((Name,Email),@key999)` will still be faster than `NAME LIKE '%'+@key999+'%' OR Email LIKE ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`It seems like a trivial task`, it's not, it's one of the most inefficient queries. That's why almost all autocomplete filters use StartsWith instead of Contains. Or use a dedicated full text search engine like Elastic.

It looks like what you try to do is generate a series of `LIKE '%..%'` clauses combined by `OR`. Clauses like this can't take advantage of any indexes so end up scanning the entire table.

While `Any` in Boolean Algebra. is equivalent to multiple `OR` expressions, EF Core can't make such a translation. SQL has its own `ALL` and `ANY` keywords that refer to all elements in a result set, not all conditions.

To generate the query you want you'll have to either specify the expressions explicitly, or use a library like [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit#using-predicatebuilder) to make the code a bit cleaner. It will still perform a full table scan :

```
IQueryable<Person> SearchPersons (params string[] keywords)
{
  var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Person>();

  foreach (string keyword in keywords)
  {
    string temp = keyword;
    predicate = predicate.Or (p => p.Name.Contains (temp))
                         .Or (p => p.Email.Contains (temp));
  }
  return dataContext.Persons.AsExpandable().Where (predicate);
}

...

var persons=await SearchPersons(keywords).ToListAsync();
```

**Using Full Text Search**

To make this query efficient you'd have to use SQL Server's [Full Text Search indexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search?view=sql-server-ver15). The [CONTAINS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#querying-multiple-columns-full-text-search) operator can be used to search for words in one or more fields, words near another etc. The examples show that the following queries are possible:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE CONTAINS( (Name,Email), 'John')
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE CONTAINS( Name , 'John OR Doe')
```

So I suppose both can be combined

```
SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE CONTAINS((Name,Email) , 'John OR Doe')
```

Doing the same in EF Core can be done with [EF.Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.contains?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions_Contains_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_String_System_String_) and combining all keywords with `OR`:

```
IQueryable<Person> SearchPersons (params string[] keywords)
{

  var term=String.Join(" OR ",keywords);

  return dataContext.Where( p => EF.Contains(p.Email,term) 
                              || EF.Contains(p.Name,term));
}
```

You could also use `FromSqlRaw` to specify the condition you want exactly:

```
var query="SELECT * FROM PERSONS WHERE CONTAINS((Name,Email) , @term)";
var term=String.Join(" OR ",keywords);
var query=dataContext.Persons.FromSqlRaw(query,term);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use .Contains with name, but not with email in the same time, try this

```
var persons = await context.PersonDbSet
    .Where(person => 
    EF.Functions.Like(person.Name, "%John%")
 || EF.Functions.Like(person.Name, "%Doe%")
 || EF.Functions.Like(person.Email, "%John%")
 || EF.Functions.Like(person.Email, "%Doe%")
).ToListAsync();
```